# Why doesn't this gradient work on IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-9, gradient

CSS:

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 29%, #999999 65%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 29%, #999999 65%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 29%, #999999 65%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 29%, #999999 65%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #000000 29%, #999999 65%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,  left bottom,    left top,   color-stop(0.29, #000000),  color-stop(0.65, #999999));
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#999999');
```

Why won't the IE version of gradient work? I can't seem to find what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the GradientType attribute:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#999999', GradientType=0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#999999',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 *

background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(153,153,153,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
```